# How to fix defaut Debian 7 apache2 install (Forbidden message on every page)

Tags: php, apache, debian

I installed ,reinstalled and resinatlled again and again ,apache2 into a new server ,always using default and modified config files ( trying to fix it).
No matter what link i try toaccess i get a :

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) Server at xx.xxx.xxx.xx Port 80
```

i changed permisions of /var/www and user and group of this dir is www-data

I did all i knew but no succes.
Any ideeas?

Comment: Step 1 is to read the error log. It will tell you whether file permissions or the server configuration generated the error.  Did you add a new DocumentRoot or Alias / ?

Comment: I did not changed any config files . All was default config files.I installed it just using apt-get .Default config files did not worked so I tried to copy all /etc/apache2 config files from another server who is working but did not worked too. i also did chmod and chown on /var/www . Nothing fixed . I had to resintall debian using KVM console and a netinstall cd . I think is because of the debian cd my hosting company has.I never faced this.

Comment: This is the kind of wheel-spinning that occurs when you don't read the error_log.

Comment: read all logs ,including /var/log/apache2/access and erorr .Goggle send me to posts but with not a resolution.I found some ppls having this error too but no luck

Comment: Why not include the verbatim log entry here?

Comment: I would include it but I had already to resinstall the server .I reinstalled it using a netinstall cd and all was good. I still think was smth in the install cd the hosting company used.I never faced that problm and I use debian all time in all dedicated and vps , I have just debian

Comment: Most likely you've mistakenly "did chmod and chown on /var/www". Make sure that `/var/www` is readable for user/group `www-data`.